# Flutter How to access index from another class

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Im trying to use the index in rendit_fjalet_quiz.dart witch i used in List.generate, i want to use it on renditfjalet_button.dart at the onPressed so like data[index+1].word, in onPressed, so the index in rendit_fjalet_quiz.dart, i want to use it on renditfjalet_button.dart

rendit_fjalet_quiz.dart

```
        body: FutureBuilder<List<QuizInfo>?>(
            future: futureData,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                List<QuizInfo>? data = snapshot.data;
                data?.sort((a,b) => a.level.compareTo(b.level));

                return Stack(children: [
                  Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage(
                                'assets/background.PNG',
                              ),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                        child: GridView.count(
                          crossAxisCount: 4,
                          children: List.generate(data!.length, (index) {
                            return InkWell(
                              splashColor: Colors.blue.withAlpha(20),
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) =>
                                            RenditFjaletButton(
                                              QuizList: data[index].word,
                                            )));
                              },
                              child: Card(
                                elevation: 3.0,
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                                child: Container(
                                  child: Align(
                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                      child: Container(
                                        child: Text(
                                          '${data[index].level}',
                                          style: GoogleFonts.fredokaOne(
                                              textStyle: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 30.0.sp,
                                            color: Color(0xFF50CFFD),
                                          )),
```

renditfjalet_button.dart

```
Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 110),
                child: FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/next_small.png',
                      height: 80,
                      width: 80,
                    )))),
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand fully but  create a class and extend ChangeNotifyer  and create index variable then you can access it anywhere in the file using provider, if button is pressed you can update it with notifyListener().